# Rename a file name with regex

Tags: regex, shell, rename, aix

I have a set of files (`ABC.AM.*.*.20*.*`) in a folder

e.g.: `ABC.AM.00.13.201106.00014`, and I need to rename this to `ABC.AM.00.13.201106.01014`. I am in AIX so rename command is not available.

just a pseudo script

```
for i in `ls ABC.AM.*.*.20*.*`
do
        mv $i DESIRED_file_name
done
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure rename is open source, and will probably build just fine on AIX.

Comment: @William Pursell Well, I am not supposed to do it..is there any work around ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not supposed to do it"?  Do you mean you can't install it in /usr/bin?  If you have write permission in your home directory, you can always try --prefix=$HOME and install there.  (But I wouldn't bother: the functionality provided by rename is easy enough to get with simple shell scripts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for arg in ABC.AM.*.*.20*.*
do
  newarg="$(echo "$arg" | sed 's/\(.*\..\)0\(.*\)/\11\2/')"
  if [ "$newarg" != "" ];then
    mv "$arg" "$newarg" 
  fi
done
```

Comment: Why would you discard the errors?  If a file doesn't get moved, the user will certainly want to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what the replacement is that you want to make, but for the particular example you give, you can do:

```
for ...; do
    mv $i ${i/00014/01014}
done
```

A common technique for this sort of thing is to use sed to generate a new filename:

```
for old_name in ...; do
  new_name=$( echo $old_name | sed -e '...' )
  mv $old_name $new_name
done
```

When doing this sort of thing, it is a good idea to replace 'mv' with 'echo' and make sure you have the replacement that you want, then re-run the command using 'mv'.

In your case, you might be wanting to use something like:

```
sed -e 's/000\([0-9]\{2\}\)$/010\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply ..
I just want to replace the zero with 1 at 2nd position 
eg 00014/01014 00015/01015 00004/01004